# Emacs font sizing with Ctrl key and mouse scroll

Tags: emacs, mouseevent, font-size

notepad++ allow me to increase the font size when I hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key and rotate the mouse middle scroll button to forward.

In the same way, the when I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and rotate the mouse middle scroll button backward, the fond size reduces.

How can I get the same with Emacs?

Comment: You have your answers below but do you really do this that often?

Comment: Yes, I often do maximize the font when I explain the code to my team. Even it was useful in projector at the time of presentation

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294664/how-to-set-the-font-size-in-emacs

Comment: It's emacs dude, why do you want to use your mouse? C-x C-+ is the way!

Comment: Xah Lee has the best answer, OS-independent. Describe key with `C-h k C-<scroll-up>`. So, for windows, I get `(kbd "<C-wheel-up>")`. From http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_mouse_wheel_config.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

code for [AlexCombas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091881/emacs-font-sizing-with-ctrl-key-and-mouse-scroll/2092158#2092158):

```
(defun font-big ()
 (interactive)
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 
  (+ (face-attribute 'default :height) 10)))

(defun font-small ()
 (interactive)
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 
  (- (face-attribute 'default :height) 10)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-wheel-down>") 'font-small)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-wheel-up>") 'font-big)
```

Edit: for a min and a max use

```
(defun font-big ()
 (interactive)
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 
  (min 720
   (+ (face-attribute 'default :height) 10))))

(defun font-small ()
 (interactive)
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 
  (max 80
   (- (face-attribute 'default :height) 10))))
```

Comment: this works. anyway where I can limit the font size to 72 maximum and 8 minimum?

Comment: `<C-wheel-down>` and `<C-wheel-up>` didn't work for me. I used `<C-mouse-5>` and `<C-mouse-4>`, which works fine. (I'm on ArchLinux, if it matters)

Comment: I used the example code, and added the following to just before the final close-parentheses of functions `font-big` and `font-small`, so that the message line tells what the new height is when the commands are executed: `(message "Default face height set to %d" (face-attribute 'default :height))`

Answer (score 22):

with emacs23 you can add following lines to your .emacs.el:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-4>") 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-5>") 'text-scale-increase)
```

Comment: I use emacs 23.1.5 on windows. but I could not make it working

Comment: +1 Not sure what the mouse-4 and mouse-5 are, but this works perfectly for me, so thanks!  (global-set-key (kbd "<C-wheel-down>") 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-wheel-up>") 'text-scale-increase)

Comment: on a clean ubuntu installation, C-mouse-4 and C-mouse-5 are associated to quick scrolling, so I'm using M-mouse-4 and M-mouse-5 (but the s- prefix is also available).

Comment: @mariotomo If you customize the mouse-wheel-scroll-amount variable, you can change the key which is bound to quick-scrolling, and then use these keys for zooming instead.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work for *any* text. I.e. I have in the .emacs config a line `...'(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "dim gray" :slant italic :weight bold :height 71 :family "purisa")))`. This is sets a font/size for a comments, and this font doesn't react for some reason on the `text-scale-decrease` function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-4>") (lambda () (interactive) (text-scale-decrease 1)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-5>") (lambda () (interactive) (text-scale-increase 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically I can give you the answer to this, but someone more skilled than me is going to have to write the lisp I'm just a little to busy atm to figure it out for myself.

If nobody responds by tomorrow I'll hit the books and figure it out.

What needs to be done:
Write a function (font-big) which does this:

1. font-default-size = font-default-size+1`
2. Then re-evaluate all open buffers.

Then Bind the function to a key (define-key map [C-wheel-up] 'font-big)

Then do the same for (font-small).

I hope I get at least partial credits for the idea :)

Comment: thanks for idea :-). looking for lisp expert to write a function

Answer (score 1):

[**Zoom Frame**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/zoom-frm.el) is what you want. I do exactly what you describe all the time. After loading `zoom-frm.el`, add some bindings such as these:

```
    (global-set-key [S-mouse-1]   'zoom-in)
    (global-set-key [C-S-mouse-1] 'zoom-out)
    (global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-down-event)) 'zoom-in)
    (global-set-key (vector (list 'control mouse-wheel-up-event))   'zoom-out)
```

See also: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts#ChangingFontSize

Comment: you rock. I would play around these settings. I made the *zoom* with others suggestion. This one comes with emacs could reduce my emacs configuration.

Comment: That might well work, but as you say, using those commands requires adding `zoom-frm.el` to `.emacs.d/lisp/`, which requires adding `frame-cmds.el`, which requires adding yet further files, all huge. I balk at adding all that stuff to my Emacs setup just to get simple font-zooming functionality. @cobbal's answer does the trick without requiring anything extra.

Comment: @TeemuLeisti: No. Only three files are needed: (1) `zoom-frm.el`, (2) `frame-cmds.el`, and (3) `frame-fns.el`. The files are separate precisely because someone can use #3 without #1 or #2, or use #2 without #1. If this were available only as a Zoom "package" then that would be all you could do: always load all three. Oh, and *none* of them are "*huge*": about 100KB for all 3 together, without comments. Anyway, please don't feel obliged to use any of them.

Comment: It's just that if one only wants to get this simple zoom functionality to work with the mouse, cobbal's answer works fine. Anyway, I take back the "huge", and meant no offence. It seems that the files implement a lot of useful functionality.