# Bind key to increase / decrease font size in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-size

In my terminal (I have [terminator](http://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator)) I can use the key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> to increase / decrease the font size.

In emacs I can do the following to set the font-height:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 70)
```

But I do not know how to increase / decrease it. How could I easily add this to my emacs configuration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs font sizing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091881/729907).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs zoom in/zoom out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5533110/729907)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs zoom in/out globally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18783227/729907).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I think you want `C-x C-+` or `C-x C--`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that, even after using Emacs for over 7 years now.

Answer (score 18):

I'd suggest:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key (kbd "C--") 'text-scale-decrease)
```

While the default keybindings mentioned by @Stefan do the job, I like to have the more commonly established keybindings as well. Btw, <kbd>C-x C-=</kbd> increases the font size as well and <kbd>C-x C-0</kbd> restores the default font size.

Comment: FWIW: That removes the possibility of using `C--` as a negative prefix arg, something that most people use very often.

Comment: There's always `M--` (which is arguably easier to press as it involves the use of just one pinky).

Answer (score 16):

`C-x C-+` and `C-x C--` gives you only ***part*** of the answer: text scaling a buffer.

You can change the font size for a given ***frame*** (across all windows/buffers in that frame), or you can change the (apparent) font size for a given ***buffer*** (across all windows/frames).
The latter is called **text scaling**, and it is what vanilla Emacs `C-x C-+` and `C-x C--` give you.

Library [`zoom-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el) gives you both kinds of zooming with the same command.  Bind the same command, `zoom-in/out`, to both `C-x C--` and `C-x C-+`.  It zooms either the frame or the buffer, in and out.  A plain prefix arg toggles between zooming frames and zooming buffers.  Bind it also to mouse keys (I use `S-mouse-1` (in) and `C-S-mouse-1` (out) and to the mouse wheel (in/out).

Library [`face-remap+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/face-remap%2b.el) fixes text scaling so that the window size shrinks or grows to accommodate the changing text size, which can free up screen real estate.

[This EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts#toc4) has more info about this frequently asked question.

Comment: Works on Emac 29.1 !

Answer (score 6):

Check purcell's .emacs.d and his font [utils](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-fonts.el).

Comment: Steve Purcell has factored his text scale utilities into a nice little minor mode: [purcell/default-text-scale](https://github.com/purcell/default-text-scale).  It's available in Melpa.

Answer (score 6):

And for mouse wheel changes with control key pressed:

```
(global-set-key [C-mouse-4] '(lambda () (interactive) (text-scale-increase 1)))
(global-set-key [C-mouse-5] '(lambda () (interactive) (text-scale-decrease 1)))
```

That works okay, but it's buffer local. The following code changes the frame font height for all buffers with control + mouse wheel/trackpad:

```
(defun change-font-height (delta)
  (set-face-attribute 'default 
                      (selected-frame)
                      :height (+ (face-attribute 'default :height) delta)))
(global-set-key [C-mouse-4] '(lambda () (interactive) (change-font-height +4)))
(global-set-key [C-mouse-5] '(lambda () (interactive) (change-font-height -4)))
```