# emacs zoom in/out globally

Tags: emacs, font-size, zooming

I know that I can zoom in/out using C-x C-+, but this applies only to the current file. Once I open another one, the text goes back to the default value and it's really tiresome to do it over and over. How can I keep the zoom level global for the current emacs session?

I know it's possible to set this in the init file if you know the exact font size, which I don't. Plus, I don't want to keep it that permanent - I usually need this when I'm without an external screen for a couple of hours or connected to a beamer while giving a presentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase/decrease font size in an emacs frame (not just buffer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705984/increase-decrease-font-size-in-an-emacs-frame-not-just-buffer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This piece of code modify the zoom in/out functionality to apply the commands to every buffer.  That should achieve what you are trying to do.

```
(defadvice text-scale-increase (around all-buffers (arg) activate)
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      ad-do-it)))
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Added it to my init file. You should maybe mention the method to [this related discussion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GlobalTextScaleMode) I just bumped into.

Comment: OK, great! Although, the first method on the page works for new files you visit and yours only works for all the open buffers (just noticed that now). Maybe it's because they also set the `text-scale-mode-amount` or something - I don't really know elisp.

Answer (score 9):

*All* of the answers given here, and more, are available on the
EmacsWiki page dedicated to the question of [setting and changing font
size](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts#ChangingFontSize), including changing it incrementally.

The answer from @abo-abo is on the right track, regardless of whether
you think the size he used in the example code was too big, and
regardless of whether the solution does not address incremental
adjustment.

The answer from @juanleon essentially makes text scaling simulate
changing the default character size (@abo-abo's answer).

The point of *text scaling* is to scale the *buffer* text (one buffer, no
matter where it is shown), not the *frame* text (all buffers shown in
the frame).  But if you want all buffers to have their text size
changed in a given frame then there is no reason to bother with text
scaling in that case: just change the font size.

You can do either or both (scale the buffer text everywhere or zoom a
frame), and do so incrementally, using the same command, if you use
command `zoom-in/out` from library
[`zoom-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/zoom-frm.el).

On the other hand, if you really do want to incrementally change the
text size of *all buffers in all frames*, then the best approaches are
either (1) @juanleon's suggestion or (2) incrementally zoom the standard face
**`default`**.

To do the latter, you can use commands `zoom-all-frames-in` and
`zoom-all-frames-out` in library
[`zoom-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/zoom-frm.el)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the implications of scaling w.r.t. frames and buffers. Like you said - I really want to change the text size in all buffers and frames, so [this method from the wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GlobalTextScaleMode#toc1) and juanleon's answer work for me. I'll keep the zoom-frm.el in mind too.

Answer (score 8):

Just paste this in `*scratch*` and evaluate (with <kbd>C-j</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>):

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 150)
```

There's nothing wrong in putting this in the init file
and commenting it out later, when you don't need it.

Comment: Hm, this just made my window so large it went outside of the screen - this is exactly why I would want to avoid guessing the exact font sizes for some strange screen I'm connected to and I don't know the resolution of. I like the option of iteratively zooming in I get with C-x C-+ and I just want to persist that value throughout the session. That's the same behaviour I have, for example, in a web browser.

Answer (score 5):

Its possible to scale all text (including status-line & line-numbers) using a little mode that handles this exact problem: [purcell/default-text-scale](https://github.com/purcell/default-text-scale).  It's available in Melpa.

This scales all text to avoid text scale mismatch such as line-numbers of fill-column indicator being offset incorrectly.

The other answers here either don't work for new buffers or require too much manual intervention.

Comment: Works great! seems the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

> connected to a beamer while giving a presentation.

There is another package for that!

[emacs-presentation-mode](https://github.com/zonuexe/emacs-presentation-mode)

Quoting from the site

1. Execute `M-x presentation-mode` to start the presentation.
2. Adjust scale size by `C-x C-+` or `C-x C--`
   See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Scale.html
3. After the presentation, execute `M-x presentation-mode` again.
4. And then execute `M-x presentation-mode` again, the last scale will be reproduced.
5. If you want to persistize its size as the default size of presentation-mode
   after restarting Emacs, set `presentation-default-text-scale`.

It's also have [description of differences](https://github.com/zonuexe/emacs-presentation-mode#difference-from-other-methods) from other similar modes/package.