# Change font settings in emacs

Tags: emacs, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the font size in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294664/how-to-set-the-font-size-in-emacs)

How can i change font name and font size in emacs?

I want to use a bigger font and textmate like font. If you have any suggestions for font name please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts -- You can also search here (S.O.) for similar questions.  I believe this has been asked and answered more than once.