# emacs font customization for tired eyes

Tags: emacs

I've been using the emacs that is bundled with the Mac OS X Terminal and it is fine, but it is an older version. I like it because I can easily control the entire Terminal font size in OS X easily.

I installed the most recent version of emacs which appears to be a different animal. It's a pseudo-gui with buttons and it is outside the Terminal environment. I've been trying to figure out how to adjust the font size of the screen with no luck. Anyone can help?

Maybe I'm dumb but I rather prefer the text-only nature of the older emacs version I was using. Trying to force a menu/mouse system in there seems to go against the primitive beauty of the system.

Comment: The Emacs GUI isn't just pseudo. It can do stuff like display different font sizes or images within a buffer that are impossible in a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic reference for font customization is: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingFaces

If you don't want to do customization via the emacs customize feature (I don't care for it myself), then this question has a good answer: [How to set the font size in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294664/how-to-set-the-font-size-in-emacs)

As for the gui jibba jabba, here's what I have in my .emacs:

```
(if (fboundp 'scroll-bar-mode) (scroll-bar-mode -1))
(if (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode) (tool-bar-mode -1))
(if (fboundp 'menu-bar-mode) (menu-bar-mode -1))
```

Turns all of that off. :-)

edit:

I suggest using the same emacs file and have a test for the NextStep libraries used in the GUI....

```
(when (featurep 'ns) 
  ;; do GUI stuff like font fiddling
  )
```

Comment: where does one place the .emacs for it to be relevant? I have a .emacs that is also there for the other version of emacs installed on OS X so I don't want them to conflict.

Comment: thanks, I have another question on this but I will make it a new question in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Type this:

```
M-x text-scale-adjust
```

Then you can use the key:

- `+`: Increasing the default face height by one step.
- `-`: Decreasing the default face height by one step.
- `0`: Reset the default face height to the global default.

Comment: this is certainly useful, thanks. but it appears to adjust only the current buffer, while not the whole environment.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like what you want is to customize face `default`.