# Increase line height in Spacemacs

Tags: emacs, line, spacemacs

I'm intending to increase the height of each line in Spacemacs. I tried to put some code into `user-config` block in the `.spacemacs` file in my home directory like below, but the line height doesn't change at all:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  '(add-text-properties (point-min) (point-max)
                 '(line-spacing 0.25 line-height 1.25))
  )
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Spacemacs? I have just started to use Spacemacs for a week so I'm totally a newbie.

Comment: `line-spacing` is a buffer-local variable that can be customized.  The `:height` property is generally adjusted by customizing a particular face such as the `default` face.  You can Google each one individually to find out how to do this with regular Emacs.  I have no idea how to do this with Spacemacs.  **How to set the font size in Emacs?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294664/how-to-set-the-font-size-in-emacs and see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineSpacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while searching for the solution, I found out that there are lots of tricks to do to increase the line height, while keeping the text appearing at the center of the line. So I tried to modify the font instead using `FontForge` (increase the top and bottom space of the font).

For people who may want to achieve the same thing, I'd like to say that using `FontForge` to create a new font that suit you is far easier than finding a way to do it via configuration in Spacemacs.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, evaluating `(setq line-spacing 2)` in a buffer increases the line spacing.

You can add `(setq-default line-spacing 2)` to your .emacs file to change it globally. `setq` wouldn't work because `line-spacing` is a buffer-local variable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you can the emacs UI to customize the vertical spacing. You do this by:
1. `M-x`
2. Type `customize variable` then press enter
3. Type `line-spacing` then press enter

You'll be taken to a UI menu for customizing the line spacing variable. 
On the line that says `line spacing`, go to the button that says `value menu`, press enter, press `1` to use a custom value. Then in the box to the right, you can change the value from `0.0` to whatever you'd like!

Then make sure to hit the `save and apply` button!